# Yii2 swiftmailer linux dont send emails

Tags: php, email, yii2, swiftmailer

I have problem using swiftmailer with yii2. I write code on dev machine which runs in windows and it work smoothly. But when I move the same code to the production site, swiftmailer is not sending email but it save email to file. I send mail from console

composer.json

```
 "require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "dev-master",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0",
```

main.php

```
        'mailer' => [
       'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 'xxx',
            'password' => 'xxx',
            'port' => '587',
            'encryption' => 'tls',
            'streamOptions' => [
                'ssl' => [
                    'allow_self_signed' => true,
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'verify_peer_name' => false,
                ],
            ]
        ],
        'useFileTransport' => false,

    ],
```

sendEmail.php

```
        $res  = \Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
            ->setFrom("stat@test.net")
            ->setTo(self::getRecipients())
            ->setHtmlBody($data)->setSubject("Stat Report ".date("d.m.Y H:i"))
            ->send();
```

What should be wrong. There is no error written in any log.

Comment: can you check what is the value of `$res`? If it is not `false`, then most likely the problem is not with the swiftmailer, and no errors will be logged because there's no error. Have you checked the spam folder of the email?

Comment: $res  = 1
Yes, I have checked for spam. Also, email is saved to file even by using setting  'useFileTransport' => false,

Comment: when you say log, is it the Yii-swiftmailer logger? If not, see my answer below.

Comment: definitely none of my business, but I recommend that you hide your password

Comment: Thx pass changed. Forgot about this.

Comment: verify your config file, if  on live it  is not picking up from `common/config/main-local.php`

Comment: You were right. In the main-local file was another mailer config. Thank you. I should check this at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm if there's no error by `try-catch`-ing it:

```
try {
    $res  = \Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
        ->setFrom("stat@test.net")
        ->setTo(self::getRecipients())
        ->setHtmlBody($data)->setSubject("Stat Report ".date("d.m.Y H:i"))
        ->send()
}
catch (\Swift_TransportException $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

Or try the logger for [Yii-swiftmalier](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-swiftmailer-logger.html) :

```
[
    'components' => [
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'enableSwiftMailerLogging' => true,
        ],
     ],
    // ...
],
```

Comment: There is no error cathed.  Also enableSwiftMailerLogging does not create any records.

Answer (score 0):

Try without `streamOptions`, like:

```
 'mailer' => [
      'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
      'useFileTransport' => false,
      'transport' => [
          'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
          'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
          'username' => 'xxx',
          'password' => 'xxx',
          'port' => '587',
          'encryption' => 'tls',
      ],
  ],
```